# Get list of tags of remote repository without cloning using libgit2

Tags: c++, git, libgit2

Using this git command I can get all of the available tags of a remote repository without having to clone it:

```
git ls-remote --tags https://github.com/blender/blender.git
```

I want to replicate this using `libgit2`.

I can use `git_tag_list` (https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/tag/git_tag_list) to get a list of tags, but it requires a `git_repository` object. I can use `git_repository_open` to create a `git_repository` object, but that only works if the repository has been cloned and exists locally on the disk. I can't seem to find any way to create a `git_repository` object using a remote repository URL.

The libgit2 examples have an implementation for the `ls-remote` command, so it must be possible somehow:

```cpp
static int use_remote(git_repository *repo, char *name)
{
    git_remote *remote = NULL;
    int error;
    const git_remote_head **refs;
    size_t refs_len, i;
    git_remote_callbacks callbacks = GIT_REMOTE_CALLBACKS_INIT;

    /* Find the remote by name */
    error = git_remote_lookup(&remote, repo, name);
    if (error < 0) {
        error = git_remote_create_anonymous(&remote, repo, name);
        if (error < 0)
            goto cleanup;
    }

    /**
     * Connect to the remote and call the printing function for
     * each of the remote references.
     */
    callbacks.credentials = cred_acquire_cb;

    error = git_remote_connect(remote, GIT_DIRECTION_FETCH, &callbacks, NULL, NULL);
    if (error < 0)
        goto cleanup;

    /**
     * Get the list of references on the remote and print out
     * their name next to what they point to.
     */
    if (git_remote_ls(&refs, &refs_len, remote) < 0)
        goto cleanup;

    for (i = 0; i < refs_len; i++) {
        char oid[GIT_OID_SHA1_HEXSIZE + 1] = {0};
        git_oid_fmt(oid, &refs[i]->oid);
        printf("%s\t%s\n", oid, refs[i]->name);
    }

cleanup:
    git_remote_free(remote);
    return error;
}

/** Entry point for this command */
int lg2_ls_remote(git_repository *repo, int argc, char **argv)
{
    int error;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s ls-remote <remote>\n", argv[-1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    error = use_remote(repo, argv[1]);

    return error;
}
```

(https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/ac0f2245510f6c75db1b1e7af7ca01c15dec26bc/examples/ls-remote.c)

Unfortunately this command also requires a `git_repository` object, so I'm at a bit of a loss. Is this currently not possible without cloning first?

Comment: It looks like `git_remote_ls(&refs, &refs_len, remote)` will get you the list of all references from the remote. Tags are just references whose name start with `refs/tags/`, so you can just keep those -- the end result will be the same as `git ls-remote --tags`.

Comment: @LeGEC Will you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `git_remote_ls(&refs, &refs_len, remote)` will get you the list of all references from the remote.

Tags are just references whose name start with `refs/tags/`, so you can just keep those -- the end result will be the same as `git ls-remote --tags`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `lg2_ls_remote()` with `nullptr` for `git_repository` parameter, and it would remote lookup without cloning.